# gRPC Server Threading Model C#

Tags: c#, grpc

Can some one tell me how the threading model of the C# implementation of gRPC-server works?
Is there one thread per service? One thread per call? One thread per client? Only one thread for all?

I'm asking because I'm not sure how I have to access my (local) resources, if I have multiple clients calling my RPCs. Do I need to lock everything and make it thread-safe? Or behaves the server like an event loop and only one call is processed at a time (no locking required)?

Comment: When you implement a gRPC service you implement asynchronous methods. I wouldn't rely on all the invocations being on the same thread, or staying on the same thread between `await` expressions either.

Comment: @JonSkeet Your're right. I should expect the worst case scenario, because the documentation says nothing/makes no guarantees about the threading model.

Comment: I wouldn't say that's "worst case" - I'd say it's the "most natural case". It would be very unusual for a server to guarantee that it would only process a single request at a time.